# ConnectTimeoutException class in httpclient instead for commons-httpclient

Tags: java, maven, httpclient, apache-commons-httpclient

I have updgraded to httpclient from commons-httpclient for security vulnerability issues.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient

But, can not find ConnectTimeoutException class in httpclient.

What is the class for ConnectTimeoutException in httpclient?

**commons-httpclient**

```
<exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

**httpclient**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `ConnectTimeoutException` class in HttpClient 4.5.14.
Try using:

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException
```

For more information, please see [ConnectTimeoutException](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ConnectTimeoutException.html)

Comment: This class is missing in 5.3 version

Comment: @Nidhi257 It is not missing, from 5.x version, the package names are changed. Try using `import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ConnectTimeoutException`